# Could any help to solve the error "Undefined symbols for architecture i386"?

Tags: c, macos, assembly, x86, hybrid

On mac OS(which has intel inside), I tried to make a simple x86 hybrid program with main module written in C and a function written in x86 assembly language (NASM assembler).

Then, the following function is to reverse the string of the argument.

My C code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *revstring(char *s);
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
for (int i=1; i<argc; i++){
    printf("%s->", argv[i]);
    printf("%s\n", revstring(argv[i]));
    }
}
```

Then my assembly code

```
    section .text
    global revstring
revstring:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    mov     eax, [ebp+8]
    mov     ecx, eax
find_end:
    mov     dl, [eax]
    inc     eax
    test    dl, dl
    jnz     find_end
    sub     eax, 2
    
swap:
    cmp     eax, ecx
    jbe     fin
    
    mov     dl, [eax]
    xchg    dl, [ecx]
    mov     [eax], dl
    dec     eax
    inc     ecx
    jmp     swap

fin:
    mov     eax, [ebp+8]
    pop     ebp
    ret
```

Then I built the program by using these command

```
cc -m32 -std=c99 -c revs.c
nasm -f elf32 revstring.s
cc -m32 -o revs revs.o revstring.o
```

But the following error occured.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file revstring.o, building for macOS-i386 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 )
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, missing required architecture i386 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_printf", referenced from:
      _main in revs.o
  "_revstring", referenced from:
      _main in revs.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I googled solutions many times, but I couldn't find it. So, could anyone help me?

Comment: If this is a MacOS machine you should probably be using macho32, not elf32, for your nasm emission. Just saying.

Comment: Current versions of MacOS don't support 32-bit code, AFAIK.  And that's been true for quite a few years.

Comment: Don't delete and repost an identical question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72131895/could-any-help-to-solve-the-error-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386 - comments there already pointed out that MacOS uses MachO object files, not ELF.

Comment: Thank you. And I'm sorry I will be careful.
Then, what command should I enter to run the program?